# ALEXA - How to send slot ID in service request

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I am creating custom Alexa skill, with custom slots. I have created predefined values for the slot and assigned an ID to each. During my tests I can see that in the service request there is no ID key-value pair:

```
"request": {
"type": "IntentRequest",
"requestId": "EdwRequestId.xXxxxxXXXx-xxXX-xXXx-xXXX-xxxXXXXXXxxx",
"intent": {
  "name": "HowToIntent",
  "slots": {
    "action": {
      "name": "action",
      "value": "clear cache"
    }
  }
},
```

Is there any possibility to pass slot ID in the request?

Comment: Can you please share your intent schema and slots created?

Comment: @VijayanathViswanathan I have posted in in the answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
"languageModel": {
"types": [
  {
    "name": "action",
    "values": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "name": {
          "value": "clear cache",
          "synonyms": [
            "flush cache",
            "clean cache"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "name": {
          "value": "perform reindex",
          "synonyms": [
            "reindex",
            "do reindex"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "id": "3",
        "name": {
          "value": "create a product",
          "synonyms": [
            "add product",
            "make product"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "id": "4",
        "name": {
          "value": "create a category",
          "synonyms": [
            "add category",
            "make category"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "element",
    "values": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "name": {
          "value": "category tree",
          "synonyms": [
            "category structure",
            "categories"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "name": {
          "value": "simple product",
          "synonyms": []
        }
      },
      {
        "id": "3",
        "name": {
          "value": "gift card",
          "synonyms": []
        }
      }
    ]
  }
],
"intents": [
  {
    "name": "AMAZON.CancelIntent",
    "samples": []
  },
  {
    "name": "AMAZON.HelpIntent",
    "samples": []
  },
  {
    "name": "AMAZON.StopIntent",
    "samples": []
  },
  {
    "name": "HowToIntent",
    "samples": [
      "how to {action}"
    ],
    "slots": [
      {
        "name": "action",
        "type": "action"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "WelcomeIntent",
    "samples": [],
    "slots": []
  },
  {
    "name": "WhatIsIntent",
    "samples": [
      "what is {element}"
    ],
    "slots": [
      {
        "name": "element",
        "type": "element"
      }
    ]
  }
],
"invocationName": "my assistant"
```

}
}